# Is there any client-server architecture for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, master-slave

I would like to build a master-slave architecture for MongoDB and satisfy the following constraint:

1. master can be read and written anytime.
2. slave sync from Server every hour, and can only be read.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What's a "client"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I've used the wrong term. I means master-slaver architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but you can get a similar setup with a replica set with the following configuration:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority = 0
cfg.members[0].slaveDelay = 3600
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

this will make member 0 of the replica set lag behind one hour, and since it has priority 0 it cannot be master and hence, can't be written to directly.

This doesn't exactly satisfy your constraints because you wanted to synchronize every hour while this setup continually updates to reflect the status of T-1h. Unfortunately, the only thing that comes to mind there is a scheduled backup operation which is probably not what you want either.

Comment: Thanks, I think the backup operator is much like what I try to do now. But still trying to seek other appropriate way since it's not actually a backup.